# My unity reset is not working when I hit an object

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I was coding a simple rolling ball game, when I came across something that I did not know how to fix. In unity I tried to reset the position of the ball when it hit an obstacle. But the code did not work and I am not sure why. Yes I enabled the tags on the "obstacle" object. When I debug.log it says that the obstacle was hit so idk what's wrong with my code. I would appreciate the help!

```
public class Over : MonoBehaviour {

public Over movement;
void OnCollisionEnter (Collision collisionInfo)
{
    if (collisionInfo.collider.tag == "obstacle")
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: please show where your "debug.log" was in this code.

Comment: Im sorry, the debug.log was where the SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex); was before. I just checked if it worked and it did.

Comment: Reload the entire scene is not the same as `reset the position of the ball` though

Comment: Oh ok, thanks alot man, so how would I implement that code into my script?

Answer (score 0):

You should keep the original position and when needed restore the position, using "transform.position".

Here is the documentation:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-position.html

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.